# CakePHP $this->Model->query return

Tags: cakephp

When i run a query like this:

```
$this->User->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE deleted = 1 AND created <= '".$created."'");
```

How do i know if there's was an error running the query?

I want to send a message to the user if there was an error something like:

```
if(!$this->User->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE deleted = 1 AND created <= '".$created."'"))
     $this->Session->setFlash('There was an error running this query');
```

This method always return 0, but the query is running without errors

Comment: is your record getting deleted...?

Comment: Yes, the query is running with no errors, and records are deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know if there is an error, or if any records were deleted?

You can use something like [$this->User->deleteAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall) instead

```
$this->User->deleteAll(array(
   'deleted' => 1 
   'created <=' => $created
));
```

It will return boolean True on success, false on failure.

Comment: Thank you i wanted to know if there was an error running the query